# "node" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. - laravel

Tags: laravel, nodejs

estoy intentando tomar un screenshot usando [browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot), el codigo es simple, solo estoy haciendo esto

```
    Browsershot::url('https://test-black.lillyqa.com/')->fullPage()->savePdf('test.pdf');
```

pero recibo el siguiente error

```
The command "node ^"F:^\Programas^\laragon^\www^\google-places-ranking^\vendor^\spatie^\browsershot^\src/../bin/browser.js^" ^"^{^\^"url^\^":^\^"https:^\/^\/test-black.lillyqa.com^\/^\^",^\^"action^\^":^\^"pdf^\^",^\^"options^\^":^{^\^"path^\^":^\^"test.pdf^\^",^\^"args^\^":^[^],^\^"viewport^\^":^{^\^"width^\^":800,^\^"height^\^":600^},^\^"fullPage^\^":true^}^}^"" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: F:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\public Output:
================ Error Output: ================ "node" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

y no entiendo qué podría estar fallando, gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Hola, comprobaste si tienes node instalado?

Comment: Instala nvm, es mas facil para gestionar node,

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford hola, sí, tengo node instalado

Comment: te falta tenerlo en el PATH. Agrega la carpeta de los binarios de node al PATH en las variables de entorno del sistema